# xpinyin: suppress pinyin annotation in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, cjk, xpinyin

The `pinyinscope` environment of the [`xpinyin` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpinyin) adds pinyin annotations to all Chinese characters therein, including those that appear in the footnote.

**Is it possible to suppress pinyin annotation for footnotes inside a `pinyinscope` environment (or inside an `\xpinyin*` command)?**

My current work around is to use the `\footnotemark`+`\footnotetext` combination. But this is hardly efficient when there are a lot of footnotes to be entered.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{xpinyin}

\begin{document}
\begin{pinyinscope}
文字文字文字\footnote{腳註\ inside \texttt{pinyinscope}}
\end{pinyinscope}

\begin{pinyinscope}
文字文字文字\footnotemark % work-around
\end{pinyinscope}
\footnotetext{腳註\ using \texttt{\string\footnotemark} and \texttt{\string\footnotetext}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My idea is to let the pinyin part become empty in the footnotes. To realise it I redefine the `\footnote` command and control the `format` option of the `\xpinyin` command. The package manual (in Chinese) gives details of options. The following codes do work as a workaround with both plflatex and xelatex, although I think they are a little ugly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{xpinyin}

\makeatletter
\let\oldfootnote=\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\xpinyin*[format={\@gobble}]{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pinyinscope}
文字文字文字\footnote{腳註\ inside \texttt{pinyinscope}}
\end{pinyinscope}

\begin{pinyinscope}
文字文字文字\footnotemark % work-around
\end{pinyinscope}
\footnotetext{腳註\ using \texttt{\string\footnotemark} and \texttt{\string\footnotetext}}

\end{document}
```

Anyway, I still suggest you to contact with the package author to solve this problem in essential and also expect a wiser solution.

Comment: @KevinC The authors noticed this bug yesterday and have fixed it. See their discussion at [link](https://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=134#c1)

Comment: It is an undocumented feature. I'm glad you know it.

Answer (score 4):

This feature has been added in the new version (avaliable in [`ctex-kit`](http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=134) currently). I will submit it to CTAN soon. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

**Update:** The new version is available in TeX Live 2013.

Comment: Thank you for this nice package and the prompt response! I really appreciate your devotion to ctex. I'll let you know if other issues come up `;)`